# Is there a way to get useWindowSize without the scroll bar?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vueuse

I am using useWindowSize but I want to get the same result as body.clientWidth and body.clientHeight.

Comment: There's includeScrollbar option. It's mentioned in the docs and should be visible in IDE suggestions